# Add one to many relationship with user in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, one-to-many

I am trying to make a simple bank application in ASP.NET Core and I have two problems:

1. How to make one to many relationship between `User` and `Transactions` (every user has many transactions). I tried that what is below but it doesn't work and now I'm stuck.
2. How to set the current user in form (user can't change that) when transaction will be created.

**TransactionsController**

```
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Aplikacja_Bankowa.Data;
using Aplikacja_Bankowa.Models;

namespace Aplikacja_Bankowa.Controllers
{
    public class TransactionsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
 
        public TransactionsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
 
        // GET: Transactions
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Transactions.ToListAsync());
        }
 
        // GET: Transactions/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
 
            var transactions = await _context.Transactions
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (transactions == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
 
            return View(transactions);
        }
 
        // GET: Transactions/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
 
        // POST: Transactions/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Date,Sender,Beneficient,Amount")] Transactions transactions)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(transactions);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(transactions);
        }
 
        // GET: Transactions/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
 
            var transactions = await _context.Transactions.FindAsync(id);
            if (transactions == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(transactions);
        }
 
        // POST: Transactions/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Date,Sender,Beneficient,Amount")] Transactions transactions)
        {
            if (id != transactions.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
 
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(transactions);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!TransactionsExists(transactions.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(transactions);
        }
 
        // GET: Transactions/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
 
            var transactions = await _context.Transactions
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (transactions == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
 
            return View(transactions);
        }
 
        // POST: Transactions/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var transactions = await _context.Transactions.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Transactions.Remove(transactions);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
 
        private bool TransactionsExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Transactions.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

**Models/Transactions**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Aplikacja_Bankowa.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ICollection<Transactions> UserTransactions { get; set; }
    }

    //public class UserTransaction
    //{
    //    public string UserId { get; set; }
    //    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    //    public int TransactionsId { get; set; }
    //    public Transactions Transactions { get; set; }
    //}

    public class Transactions
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Data transakcji")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public string? Sender { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Odbiorca")]
        public string? Beneficient { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Kwota")]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public Transactions Transaction { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Views/Transactions/Create.cs**

```
@model Aplikacja_Bankowa.Models.Transactions

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Transactions</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Sender" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Sender" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Sender" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Beneficient" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Beneficient" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Beneficient" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Amount" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Amount" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: First you need to mangae the roles.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true.  Second async processes may take different amount of time to complete.  So you have to send a unique ID with each request and then return the id in the response so a response can be associate with the request.

Comment: Your `Transactions` should have a reference to `ApplicationUser` instead of a cyclic reference to `Transactions`. Then you could create a transaction and assign an existing user to it.